# show picasa album in android app

Tags: android, picasa

I want to show picasa album in a grid view in my android app. I have the username/password + album id of the album from which i want to load the album.

i tried implementing this via gdata library but eclipse is giving an error on line2 in following syntax:

```
PicasawebService myService = new PicasawebService("exampleCo-exampleApp-1");
myService.setUserCredentials("liz@gmail.com", "mypassword");
```

I have also added gdata libraries in my code. Following are the names:

```
gdata-photos-2.0
gdata-client-1.0
```

Any idea what i am doing wrong? OR Please suggest any tutorials who has implemented this.

Please help!!

Comment: Got the solution for eclipse error, i need to add few more jar files  : gdata-client-meta-1.0.jar, gdata-core-1.0.jar, gdata-media-1.0.jar, google-collect-1.0-rc1.jar, servlet-api.jar, activation.jar.  But after when i run my project i am getting a Verify Error. "11-03 12:00:16.693: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1702): java.lang.VerifyError: com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService". PLease help.

Comment: it would probably help if you posted *what* error you are getting (including stack trace!). It doesn't help us much that you just say "an error on line2"...

Comment: @mudit we got solution of this share some code it is very usefull to me. How to show Picasa album in application?